# node.js `cron` module not working on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I have `cron` module installed on my local machine, I deploying my app on heroku.

```
new cronJob('00 00 * * * *', function () {
    log.info('every hour');
}, null, true);

new cronJob('00 00 00 * * *', function () {
    log.info('every day');
}, null, true);
```

First cronJob executes `log.info` function every hour, and second - every day. Script works perfectly on my local machine, but not working on heroku.

Comment: did you add it into your package.json file https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn yes, of course. all modules except this work perfectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node-cron does not work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289269/node-cron-does-not-work-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Your cron job is never ran because Heroku dyno went to sleep. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-sleeping

Try waking it up by visiting some URL in your app and see if cron job gets executed.

In order to have your cron jobs executed you need to keep Heroku app awake 24/7. To make sure your Heroku app does not go to sleep, install the NewRelic Heroku Addon you can set up availability monitoring. You provide a URL which NewRelic pings every 30 seconds, therefore keeping your app awake. The intended purpose of this feature is to alert you if your site goes down for business and performance reasons, but it has the added benefit of preventing your app from idling.

Hope it helps!